# How to deploy a remove development server with Flutter Web?

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, flutter-web

I sometimes develop remotely thanks to vscode-remote and nginx reverse proxy

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-port=4000
```

I want to open flutter web dev server on other ip than http://localhost:4000

I can do that with nginx and webpack-dev-server

There is no way to open in other browser except chrome (some proxy dependencies interal from chrome)

nginx config file

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for opening the flutter web app in other browser during development this is not possible as of now. Check the note [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web) on top of this link. One option is to run `flutter build web` and host the `build\web` folder. Once hosted this can be opened in any browser like **Firefox** or so. But I guess you cannot debug in this mode.